# How can I load UIProgressView status?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiprogressview

I would like to load the progressview's status, when I start my app again. I have an int, which I save every time.  the progressview is full if the int = 18.

I used this code:

```
IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress1;


-(void)progress1{
    [progress1  setProgress:progress1.progress+0.055];

}
```

in viewdidappear/viewdidload:

```
[progress1 setProgress:0.0];
```

so if I answered 9/18 , and my progress bar is at half, and I close my app, next time when I start again, it still at half, not 0.0

Comment: What about multitasking? Do you want it saved when it's manually terminated through the multitasking bar?

Comment: I only would like to save it when I press a button, and load when I start the app again.

Comment: it s a quiz. just save the player's status of a level. How many correct answer did he do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button press method add this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setFloat:[progress1 progress] forKey:@"progress"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[progress1 setProgress:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"progress"];
```